# Stopping SourceTree 2.2 Crash After External Merge Using TortoiseMerge

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Ever since my most recent update to SourceTree, version 2.2, it's crashed after every external merge I've done. My tool of choice is TortoiseMerge.

Has anyone gotten the same behaviour and, if so, know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: 2.2 freezes on internal merges as well (Yosemite 10.10.5) reverted back to 2.1. That and I'm not a fan of the new skin.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. When doing a KDiff merging, at the moment of saving the merged file : SourceTree stops working. The file is however correctly saved but I have to restart SourceTree each time.

This appends since I updated to version 1.8.2.

This is the Window log trace:

```
SourceTree.exe
Version du Framework : v4.0.30319
Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée.
Informations sur l'exception : System.NullReferenceException
Pile :
   à SourceTree.ViewModel.VisualMergeWindowViewModel.MergeProcessOnCompleted(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   à SourceTree.Utils.RepoProcess.OnCompleted()
   à SourceTree.Utils.RepoProcess.DoCompletionFunctions()
   à System.Diagnostics.Process.RaiseOnExited()
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   à System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
```

I need a solution to keep using SourceTree UI for launch merging process. Help!

I may have a temporary solution:

Launch the external merging tool:

1. Save your merged file with this same tool
2. Instead of closing the external merge tool, come back on SourceTree UI and click on "Abord" : it will close the tool without crashing.
3. The file being yet well saved, click right on it and select "mark resolved"
4. Delete all generated back up files 'created because of the previous "Abord" action)

Hope that help! It works for me

Answer (score 0):

See this link:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-4499

you can use terminal and git mergetool command